# Como importar reglas de CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Si tengo **dos** archivos css, *en la misma carpeta*:

***main.css*** en el cual tengo varias reglas, *por ejemplo*:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

*y el* ***jxcore.css(En donde aún no hay nada)***

Y dos archivos html, que son:

***main.html(respectivo para el main.css)***  *y*  ***jxcore.html(respectivo para el jxcore.css)***

*Como podría **importar** solo la regla de `body` de `main.css` a `jxcore.html` , sin tener que llamarlo desde el archivo html con `<link>`, ya que el archivo `main.css`, **posee otras reglas que no quiero**, es posible?*

Comment: Añade la regla de `body` del archivo `main.css` al archivo `jxcore.css`?

Comment: No puedes hacer eso. Podrías crear un nuevo archivo css con las reglas comunes o generar tus css utilizando sass o less para no duplicar valores.

Comment: Podrías probar, a asignarles las reglas por clases en vez de por etiquetas.

Comment: Puedes importar una hoja de estilos desde otra si no quieres llamarla desde el HTML, pero la importarás completa. Si quieres importar reglas concretas de otro archivo necesitarías un preprocesador CSS.

Comment: Estás ante un problema de organización de código. **Solución:** Organizar el código de forma que agrupes en un archivo los elementos comunes y en otros los elementos propios a uno o varios HTML. A veces no es una tarea fácil, sobre todo en proyectos ya empezados y con poca planificación... pero tarde o temprano tendrás que hacerlo. _Más vale tarde que nunca_.

Comment: blonfu, como funciona eso del preprocesador?

Comment: lo que dice Asier: SASS, Less, Stylus... También tienes PostCSS que no es un preprocesador pero se puede usar igual y tiene más cosas interesantes. Te permiten usar variables, crear funciones y cosas propias de lenguajes de programación pero para CSS.

Comment: Gracias lonfu, podrias colocarlo como respuesta:)